# Extracting two columns from different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I join two sql queries

```
 $sql = "SELECT Wpm FROM tableA limit 26"; and 
 "SELECT Rpm FROM tableB";
```

into one, and echo the results in the code below? I just want to display the two columns side by side in a table. I am not sure if the word "join" is the right one here. Thanks!

```
  <table class="tbresult">
        <tr>
            <th>Wpm</th>
            <th>Rpm</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

      include ("config.php");

****   $sql = "SELECT Wpm FROM tableA limit 26"; 
AND 
"SELECT Rpm FROM tableB";******


      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      $counter = 3;

       while($Row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $Row["Wpm"] . "</td><td>" . $Row["Rpm"] . "</td></tr>";

                $counter++;
                if($counter % 33 == 0) { ?>
    </table>

    <table class="tbresult">
        <tr>
            <th>Wpm</th>
            <th>Rpm</th>
        </tr>

        <?php }
        }
    echo "</table>";

    } else { echo "0 results"; }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: What are the structures of your tables? do they have a foreign key relationship?

Comment: what is the common column in both tables which can be used as reference to combine?

Comment: In the above  code, the 2nd query will be executed always.

Comment: I think you need to use the join condition for your sql Query

Comment: thanks. the tables don't have a foreign key relationship. I just want to display the results side by side.

Comment: SELECT Wpm, Rpm FROM tableA cross join tableB - 
see answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a "Cross Join" - a cross join produces a "carthesian product". This means it multiplies the rows of "Table A" and "Table B":

```
SELECT Wpm, Rpm FROM tableA cross join tableB
```

(details here: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

Comment: why is the answer downvoted? 
A cross join does exacty join 2 tables without a key:

SELECT Wpm, Rpm 
FROM tableA cross join tableB

Comment: Tobias, I didn't downvote your answer. someone else did. I don't know why. I'll check your suggestion. I tried to do this myself, but couldn't find a simple explanation on joins. I don't know much about mysql/php, so I can't know if your answer is good or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql = "SELECT Wpm FROM tableA limit 26";
 $sql = "SELECT Rpm FROM tableB";
```

It means the second query runs every time because first variable replaced by second.

For this you need to run separate for first and second query.

Comment: Thanks, Niraj.I don't want to run them separately, I want to join them.

Comment: sure can you than show me your table structure Please...because for join we need a common thing on both table

Comment: tableA has Wpm column which is basically letters from a to z. 26 rows. and tableB has columns ID,Rpm, Spm,Tpm,Kpm. they have no relationship.

Comment: if no relationship then how we can join operation between them

Comment: I don't know if the join is right word here, but I need a way to fetch two columns from two different tables, and can display them together.

Answer (score -1):

if columns are same and equal use UNION [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) . else its better to use JOINs than 2 select and fetch them.
anyway your first $sql are replaced by second...

Comment: $sql = "SELECT Wpm FROM tableA UNION Rpm FROM tableB"; I tried this, but didn't work.

Comment: column names should be same. you probably need JOIN.